# Always Initialize Fingerprint scanner device

Tags: c#, fingerprint

I have implemented Fingerprint scanner(Futronic FS80) in our application but there on issue before capture the Fingerprint user need to click on capture button and when user click on capture button then we Initialize the device. Here is Initialization code.

```
int defaultInterface = ScanAPIHelper.Device.BaseInterface;
                FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS[] status = ScanAPIHelper.Device.GetInterfaces();
                if (status[0] != FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS.FTRSCAN_INTERFACE_STATUS_CONNECTED)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Device not Connected");
                    return;
                }

                m_hDevice = new Device();
                m_hDevice.Open();
                m_hDevice.FastFingerDetectMethod = true;
                DeviceInfo dinfo = m_hDevice.Information;
```

We want to remove capture the button so user just put fingure on device without clicking any button.

Thanks
Atul

Answer (score 0):

you can create an [event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which detect the finger put on the device.If event occur then you can call the corresponding function for capturing the fingerprint.

Comment: If device is not Initialized then how device tell us the figure is put on device.

Comment: You should initialize the device before and check the finger put on the devise form event and when event occur you can call the code for capturing the fingerprint.